# Formatting tables so that they fit within page width

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to get a table that looks like

[image]

However, when using

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline Time-Scale & Mechanical Machine State Variables & Electrical Machine  State Variables  & Power Electronics  State Variables  \\ 
\hline Mechanical Machine (Slowest)
& Dynamic & Instantaneous & Instantaneous \\ 
\hline Electrical Machine (Middle)
& Frozen & Dynamic & Instantaneous \\ 
\hline Power Electronics (Fastest)
& Frozen & Frozen & Dynamic \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

I get a bad looking table:

[image]

How can I make the text in each box centered and how can I divide the text in one box into multiple lines? (When I tried using \ between words, it was treating that as a new table entry.)

From a previous post, I see that using tabularx instead of tabular is one possible solution.  Is that the recommend solution?

Instead of manually entering new lines, is there a way to fix the column width and prevent words from appearing partly on the end of one line and partly on the beginning of the next?

Thank you,

Kevin

Comment: The p{} option is equivalent to putting \parbox[t]{} into some other field.  However, you probably want \parbox[c]{} or \parbox[b]{}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline 
        \bfseries Time-Scale & \bfseries\specialcell{Mechanical\\Machine State\\Variables} & \bfseries\specialcell{Electrical\\Machine  State\\Variables}  & \bfseries\specialcell{Power\\Electronics  State\\Variables}  \\ 
        \hline 
        \specialcell{Mechanical\\Machine\\(Slowest)} & Dynamic & Instantaneous & Instantaneous \\ 
        \hline 
        \specialcell{Electrical\\Machine\\(Middle)} & Frozen & Dynamic & Instantaneous \\ 
        \hline 
        \specialcell{Power\\Electronics\\(Fastest)} & Frozen & Frozen & Dynamic \\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Nicer to read would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{l}}
        \toprule 
        Time-Scale & \specialcell{Mechanical\\Machine State\\Variables} & \specialcell{Electrical\\Machine  State\\Variables}  & \specialcell{Power\\Electronics  State\\Variables}  \\ 
        \midrule 
        \specialcell{Mechanical\\Machine\\(Slowest)} & Dynamic & Instantaneous & Instantaneous \\\addlinespace 
        \specialcell{Electrical\\Machine\\(Middle)} & Frozen & Dynamic & Instantaneous \\\addlinespace
        \specialcell{Power\\Electronics\\(Fastest)} & Frozen & Frozen & Dynamic \\ 
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, working perfectly.  As a minor question, how I center the table title?  I added \caption {Table Title} right after \centering, but the Table Title appears flush to the left rather than centered.

Comment: We will need to know your `\documentclass` for this. It seems as this is the desired look by your template so maybe you should not change that. The topic on how to manipulate the caption has been discussed many times on this site here. Please do a query.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Looks like you reinvented `\makecell`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Really? Don't know that. Hehe, I will have to search for that next week. I am always using that 'special cell' which I stole from some code by egreg, I believe. Not sure...